# AndEngine hangs

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing a game using andengine. On my scene i have only 3 sprites moving in the same direction. So the problem is that it sometimes hangs after less than a second and sometimes not. Interface does not respond. Logcat shows no problems at all. It looks like it hangs somewhere inside andengine, but I can't figure it out. I just managed to track it down using step over in OnManagedUpdate method of Entity class on line

entities.get(i).onUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

When i step over it just hangs and I can't step into it.

Did anybody face such problems? What it could be?

Comment: Are you using the fpslogger?

Comment: Maybe one of your `UpdateHandler`s has blocks your UpdateThread. Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug - the sprites animation rate was generated randomly and sometimes it got negative value. I'm realy sorry for such a vague question, it's just the project is large enough to take a lot of time to isolate the problem code part.